# trying to get vlookup to work with exit of textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a textbox that I want to enter a number with a scanner and have it return a value from a sheet. The scanner has auto-enter so I have tried this but get an error on LastRow information when running.

```
Private Sub TxtBoxFind_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Dim find_id As String
        Dim LastRow As Integer
        find_id = (TxtBoxFind.Text)
        LastRow = Worksheets("data").Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            MsgBox LastRow
            If Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 1).Value = find_id Then
            TxtBoxResult.Text = Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
        
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it should be `Rows.Count` not `Row.Count`

Comment: BTW, you will want to move the `MsgBox LastRow` before the loop, or you will have to hit the button over and over and over.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe it was that simple.